# How to list instances of a specific class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently have a "datetime" component, displaying a time representation and wish to change its display relative to the current time

```
var MDate = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        // this.props.date is an integer
        var d = new Date(this.props.date);
        var diff = ((new Date() - d) / 1000) | 0;

        return <time>{diff} seconds ago</time>;
    }
});
```

*(note that this is a simplified example, actual code change the formatting depending on the diff)*

I'd like to periodically refresh the component value for every instance of that component, but it seems that React does not provide a way of doing this.

So far, I've come up with this, but this seems far from ideal:

```
var MDate = React.createClass({
    componentWillMount: function() {
        MDate.items.push(this);
    },
    componentWillUnmount: function() {
        var i = MDate.items.indexOf(this);
        if (i > -1) {
            MDate.items.splice(i, 1);
        }        
    },
    render: function() { … }
}

MDate.items = [];
```

Then iterate over `MDate.items` and call forceUpdate() for each one

Is there a way of listing every mounted instance of MDate without relying on this trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the service that knows when the components should update publish an event that all the component instances listens to in `componentDidMount`. And inside that event listener you call `setState` to trigger your components to rerender.

Something like this:

```
let MDate = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return this.getState();
  },
  getState() {
    return {
      date: DateStore.get()
    };
  },
  componentDidMount() {
    DateStore.on('change', () => this.setState(this.getState()));
  },
  render() {
    let d = new Date(this.state.date);
    let diff = ((new Date() - d) / 1000) | 0;

    return <time>{diff} seconds ago</time>;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't really call `forceUpdate` or `setState` from outside of the component. This is one way to do it:

```
var MDate = React.createClass({
    componentWillMount: function() {
        this._timer = setInterval(this.update, 1000);
    },
    componentWillUnmount: function() {
        clearInterval(this._timer);
    },
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            currentDate: new Date()
        };
    },
    render: function() {
        // this.props.date is an integer
        var d = new Date(this.props.date);
        var diff = ((this.state.currentDate - d) / 1000) | 0;

        return <time>{diff} seconds ago</time>;
    },
    update() {
        this.setState({ currentDate: new Date() });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I came up with this solution (cheating using jQuery)

```
var MDate = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {tick: new Date().getTime()};
    },
    tick: function(ev) {
        this.setState({tick: ev.timeStamp})
    },
    componentWillMount: function() {
        $(document).on('date-tick', this.tick);
    },
    componentWillUnmount: function() {
        $(document).off('date-tick', this.tick);
    },
    render: function() {…}
}

window.setInterval(function() {
    $(document).trigger('date-tick')
}, 20 * 1000);
```